# my join returns 0 results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to following 3 tables: room, reservation and reservationroom

Their structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `room` (
  `roomID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hotelID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `roomtypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `roomNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `roomName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `roomName_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `roomDescription` text,
  `roomDescription_en` text,
  `roomSorder` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `roomVisible` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`roomID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `reservation` (
   `reservationID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `customerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `hotelID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `reservationCreatedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
   `reservationCreatedFromIp` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET greek NOT NULL,
   `reservationNumberOfAdults` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
   `reservationNumberOfChildrens` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
   `reservationArrivalDate` date NOT NULL,
   `reservationDepartureDate` date NOT NULL,
   `reservationCustomerComment` text CHARACTER SET greek,
   PRIMARY KEY (`reservationID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `reservationroom` (
   `reservationroomID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `reservationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `hotelID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `roomID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reservationroomID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

(please note that foreign keys have been removed from create statements for sake of simplicity)

What I am trying to do: I want to get all rooms that are not reserved for specific dates, that is only the free rooms from the specific hotel (I have its ID)

Here is the query that I have right now:

```
SELECT r.* FROM room r  
LEFT JOIN `reservationroom` rr 
ON r.`hotelID` = rr.`hotelID` 
AND r.`roomID` = rr.`roomID`
LEFT JOIN `reservation` re
ON rr.`reservationID` = re.`reservationID`
WHERE (rr.`reservationroomID` = '' 
    OR rr.`reservationroomID` IS  NULL 
    AND re.`reservationArrivalDate` >= 2014-08-27
    AND re.`reservationDepartureDate` <= 2014-08-29 
    AND r.`hotelID` = 10 
    AND r.`roomVisible` = 1);
```

This query now returns 0 results. It should return 9 records, since the hotel with ID = 10 has 9 rooms that are free (no resevations for specific dates exist in the reservation table)

Can anyone give me a hand with this please? I am trying to sort this out couple of hours, without any success.

Comment: Move your conditions for tables that are in LEFT JOINs into the JOIN criteria and out of the WHERE clause.  As things stand you have an "implied" INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `left join`, so conditions on all but the first table should be in the `on` clauses.  I think you want a query more like this:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM room r LEFT JOIN
    `reservationroom` rr 
     ON r.`hotelID` = rr.`hotelID` AND
        r.`roomID` = rr.`roomID` LEFT JOIN
    `reservation` re
      ON rr.`reservationID` = re.`reservationID` AND
         re.`reservationArrivalDate` >= 2014-08-27 AND
         re.`reservationDepartureDate` <= 2014-08-29 
WHERE r.`hotelID` = 10 AND r.`roomVisible` = 1 AND re.reservationID is null;
```

I'm not sure what the comparison is to the empty string.  It doesn't seem necessary for this purpose.

Comment: I just test it and i get the room with id 4 twice, i have no idea why however....

Comment: Can you set this up in SQL fiddle?  That sounds like a data problem.